# Is this possible to send and get back the value from google app script to html page without rendering html output?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, html5-canvas, add-on

After much discussion and R&D, image cropping is not possible with Google APP scripts. So I decided to try one using the Canvas API.

I am trying to pass the value from server script(.gs) to the HTML file and get back the value in the server side script without opening HTML output as in sidebar or model/modelLess dialog box. You can say silently call HTML, complete the process and return the value to server script method.

I tried but `getFromFileArg()` is not running when i am running the `callToHtml()`.

Is this possible with below script? what you will suggest?

**Server side (.gs)**

```
function callToHtml() {
    var ui = SlidesApp.getUi();
    var htmlTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('crop_img');
    htmlTemp["data"] = pageElements.asImage().getBlob();
    var htmlOutput = htmlTemp.evaluate();
}

function getFromFileArg(data) {
  Logger.log(data);
}
```

crop_img.html template :

```
<script>

     var data = <?= data ?>;

     //call the server script method
     google.script.run
       .withSuccessHandler(
           function(result, element) {
           element.disabled = false;
       })
       .withFailureHandler(
           function(msg, element) {
           console.log(msg);
           element.disabled = false;
       })
       .withUserObject(this)
       .getFromFileArg(data);


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "silently" call the HTML this way, no.

The HTML needs to go to the user and the user is not inside of your web app, but Google's web app (Slides), so you have to play by their rules.

You need to use one of the available [UI](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html) methods such as [`showSidebar`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html#showSidebar(Object)).  You could have the displayed HTML be a spinner or message like "processing..." while the JavaScript runs.

```js
function callToHtml() {
    var ui = SlidesApp.getUi();
    var htmlTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('crop_img');
    htmlTemp["data"] = pageElements.asImage().getBlob();
    ui.showSidebar(htmlTemp.evaluate());
}
```

Comment: thank you for your comments, but i am not outputting the HTML content.

Comment: @PuzzledBoy mea culpa, I did not read your question carefully.  I have edited it to hopefully actually answer your question.

Comment: Thank you. "spinner or message like "processing..." already were in my mind and i tried. that's why i wrote silently.. i am waiting for more suggestions , i appreciate your help .